# How we can scroll uitable in appdesigner of matlab by programming?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer, matlab-uitable

I have created a 100×100  table  by default only 20×20 cell of table is shown, also  I have an editfeild component when user input :goto AA20 or other select  cells the view of table will change and will show  that cell and cells around it
Like this:

[image]

When i write  goto AA20 in edit field  it should show this view
**[image]**

I need help to write this .
Best regards*

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Maybe posting a screenshot of what you're seeing and what you expect to see will help?

Comment: I edit my question